# Showing forms after Application.Run()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have seen plenty of questions like this one, but I keep encountering an anomaly. I'm trying to initialize some forms, call `Application.Run(...)` with a main form without showing any of the non-main forms, do some work, and then show/hide the rest of the forms dynamically. Some dummy code follows.

```
public static void Main() {
    MainForm = new DebugUserInterface(); // just a dummy form
    SubForm = new DebugUserInterface(); // ditto

    Task.Run((Action) DoWork); // schedule some work on another thread
    Application.Run(MainForm); // start the message pump
}

private static void DoWork() {
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // pretend to do some work
    SubForm.Invoke((Action) SubForm.Show); // show the other form
                                           // should occur after the message pump has started
}
```

The sub form never shows up. Interestingly, the sub form only shows up and behaves correctly if I invoke `SubForm.Show()` before starting the message pump, but I want certain forms to stay invisible, uninitialized, or even not yet existant (in the event that I want to create forms at runtime) prior to calling `Application.Run(...)`.

I am using Mono 5.0.0.100 for macOS to compile this code and test running the code on both macOS (using Mono runtime and Wine) and Windows (using .NET runtime).

Comment: At least on Windows, probably on Mono too, a Form is not committed to any specific thread until its native window is created.  And Invoke() will not do what you hope it does until that happened.  The native window is created as late as possible, that's why you need Show().  You can append `this.CreateHandle();` to the form constructor to force it to be done earlier.

Comment: You should write this as an answer, for it has solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hans's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190391/showing-forms-after-application-run/44193747#comment75394969_44190391) is accurate, but IMHO leads you down the wrong path. It's true that you can't use the `SubForm` object to get back to the correct thread, because its handle hasn't been created yet. But you have another object that *does* have a valid handle: the `MainForm` object.

In addition, you can use the `Form.Shown` event to make sure your code doesn't execute until the `MainForm` has been shown (and in particular, has a valid handle).

Finally, if you take advantage of the new `async`/`await` paradigm, you can avoid the explicit invoke altogether. The framework will do it for you.

Put that all together, and it might look something like this:

```
public static void Main() {
    MainForm = new DebugUserInterface(); // just a dummy form
    SubForm = new DebugUserInterface(); // ditto

    MainForm.Shown += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        await Task.Run(DoWork);
        SubForm.Show();
    };

    Application.Run(MainForm); // start the message pump
}

private static void DoWork() {
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // pretend to do some work
}
```

Note that with the above, using the anonymous method for the event handler, you don't even need static fields for the `MainForm` and `SubForm` variables. You could make those local variables if you wanted to.